# How to compare automatically that the configurations of our citrix are the same

Tags: citrix

Again and again we have problems with software running on citrix servers because they don't have the same configuration. Perhaps an ODBC-DNS configuration is wrong or some rights are missing.

Is there a tool to compare that the configrations of our citrix servers are the same?

Tanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commercial software like Opsware (now owned by HP, with a longer name) can do this. Not only will it compare configs, it will push the configs to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a commercial tool yet.

If your willing to exercise your scripting skills then a combination of pstools from [Sysinternals](http://live.sysinternals.com) and Windows reg command line executable in a batch file is where I would start.

Another alternative to explore is monitoring software that allows you to create custom agents. We have configured Nagios to monitor a Windows server environment by deploying custom agents that are essentially windows batch files returning a result to the Nagios monitoring server when called. There might be commercial software that has a lower learning curve you could use.